# LTspice - simulation of SPWM is giving unexpected result

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, pwm, ltspice, simulation

I am trying to make SPWM with op-amps. I also made a simple NOT gate with a simple transistor.

The first op-amp is working well when its output is not connected. When I directly connect the first op-amp's output to the transistor base (without the voltage follower), the output of the first op-amp gives unexpected behaviour such as going up and down between 4 V and 4.4 V.

That is why I put in a voltage follower to see what would happen. This time (with the voltage follower) the NOT gate (the OUT pin of the transistor) worked well, but the signal between the output of the voltage follower and the base of transistor had the same behaviour: going up and down between 4 V and 4.4 V. On the other hand, the signal behind the voltage follower was coming well.

I put my circuit and a picture of this unexpected result below. The blue line is between the follower and the base of transistor. The green line is between the first op-amp and the follower.

1. What could be the reason for this, LTspice or my circuit connections?
2. As soon as I add a new component after the circuit has been working properly for some time, every output suddenly collapses in LTspice. What is the reason for this?

[image]

(Source: My own study)

[image]
(Source: My own study)

Comment: I can see that your second opamp is not biased

Comment: Hello, yes ı forgot to put it, I changed it the result is same. I still have unexpected results  @Hari

Answer (score 1):

I simulated your circuit with some small changes.

Please see the result below.
May I know are you expecting the same.

[image]

[image]

As **Ste Kulov** suggested this is due to Vbe drop of BJT.Please see the below image.

[image]

Comment: Hello Sir, yes ı have the same outputs but why is Vb side going between 4.1V and 5V although the opamp out is going betwen 0 V and 5V ?    @Hari

Comment: @Mhan Because of the Vbe drop of the emitter-base junction of the PNP.

Comment: Hello Sir, ı can understand the Vbe drop but ı couldnt understand the the effect of Vbe drop on the Vb which is going between 4.1 and 5 V. How does it cut the voltage coming from opam in this way ? @SteKulov

Comment: Hello Sir, ı can understand the Vbe drop but ı couldnt understand the the effect of Vbe drop on the Vb which is going between 4.1 and 5 V. How does it cut the voltage coming from opam in this way ?  @Hari

Comment: @Mhan I think you might not be understanding how BJTs work.  Here are the equivalent circuits [when opamp is at 5V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLgwx.png) and when [opamp is at 0V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fui5z.png).  Does it make more sense now?  In one case there is current flowing into opamp, and in the other case there is no current (so no voltage drop).